# Which graphic-package for statistics in Ruby

Tags: ruby, graphics, statistics, gd

I want to visualize some statistical calculations with random numbers etc. in Ruby.
I heard about gd and gd2, but their gems don't seem to be supported anymore.

Do you have recommendations for creating images and graphics in Ruby?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Ruby graphic libraries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323287/ruby-graphic-libraries)

Comment: that's depressing.  In perl GD is awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best graphic processing lib for ruby [RMagic](http://rmagick.rubyforge.org/).